# Can't print to Fuji Xerox CM115W: "Filter failed"

Tags: freebsd, cups

I have a Fuji Xerox CM115W to which I'm trying to print via IPP.

All attempts to print to the printer fail in the following way (from CUPS' error_log), and display "Filter failed" in the CUPS web UI:

```
E [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Operand stack:
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] (/var/spool/cups/tmp/gs_vohclB)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Execution stack:
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1971   1   3   %oparray_pop   1970   1   3   %oparray_pop   1954   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1842   2   9   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Dictionary stack:
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] --dict:1199/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:89/200(L)--   --dict:89/200(L)--   --dict:117/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:280/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:28/32(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:22/40(L)--
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Current allocation mode is local
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Last OS error: Invalid argument
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [15/Aug/2017:21:18:46 +1000] [Job 30] Rendering completed
```

When I examine `/var/spool/cups/tmp/gs_vohclB` it's what I expect: PDF, starting with:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
% This file was generated by pdftopdf
```

Even weirder, if I open the file with Ghostscript *manually*, it works just fine:

```
➜  tmp /usr/local/bin/gs ./gs_vohclB
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

System and printer details:

```
FreeBSD x220 11.1-RELEASE 11.1-RELEASE #0 r321309: Fri Jul 21 02:08:28 UTC 2017
FUJI XEROX DocuPrint CM115/118 w
```

Can anyone suggest any further debugging steps I might take?  I've about exhausted my (limited) knowledge of CUPS.

*Edited:* I've taken my laptop to work, where it auto-detected and added a Sharp MX-3610 without any issues.  Printing to that printer works just fine.  I am now more confused than before; it seems to be *just* the Fuji that's failing :-/